# What does 'records are values not objects' mean in tidyjson

Tags: json, r

The json in the following string is correct json according to http://jsonlint.com/ but tidyjson objects:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyjson)

json <- '
    [{"country":"us","city":"Portland","topics":[{"urlkey":"videogame","name":"Video Games","id":4471},{"urlkey":"board-games","name":"Board Games","id":19585},{"urlkey":"computer-programming","name":"Computer programming","id":48471},{"urlkey":"opensource","name":"Open Source","id":563}],"joined":1416349237000,"link":"http://www.meetup.com/members/156440062","bio":"Analytics engineer.  Primarily work in the Hadoop space.","lon":-122.65,"other_services":{},"name":"Aaron Wirick","visited":1443078098000,"self":{"common":{}},"id":156440062,"state":"OR","lat":45.56,"status":"active"}]
    '
    json %>% as.tbl_json %>% gather_keys
```

I get:

```
Error in gather_keys(.) : 1 records are values not objects
```

Comment: From where comes `%>%`?

Comment: @pascal - surely it's dplyr

Comment: @Pascal - it's in the title - `tidyjson` package

Comment: `%>%` is from magrittr and is probably imported by either or both of dplyr or tidyjson.

Comment: @42-  Yes, but easier when used packages are specified in the question. Wasn't the case when I asked.

Comment: @mrflick Can you shed any insight on this issue?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what your question is, but `gather_keys` is looking for objects (key/value pairs), and you're supplying an array at the top level. That's what the error means. You can see the code: `tidyjson:::gather_keys`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in one of the comments, `gather_keys` is looking for objects, where you have an array.  What you should probably be using here is `gather_array`.

Further, the other answer uses a more brute-force approach to parsing the JSON attribute that the tidyjson package creates.  tidyjson provides methods for dealing with this in a bit cleaner pipeline if desired:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyjson)

json <- '
[{"country":"us","city":"Portland"
,"topics":[
 {"urlkey":"videogame","name":"Video Games","id":4471}
 ,{"urlkey":"board-games","name":"Board Games","id":19585}
 ,{"urlkey":"computer-programming","name":"Computer programming","id":48471}
 ,{"urlkey":"opensource","name":"Open Source","id":563}
]
,"joined":1416349237000
,"link":"http://www.meetup.com/members/156440062"
,"bio":"Analytics engineer.  Primarily work in the Hadoop space."
,"lon":-122.65,"other_services":{}
,"name":"Aaron Wirick","visited":1443078098000
,"self":{"common":{}}
,"id":156440062,"state":"OR","lat":45.56,"status":"active"
}]
'

mydf <- json %>% as.tbl_json %>% gather_array %>% 
spread_values(
 country=jstring('country')
 , city=jstring('city')
 , joined=jnumber('joined')
 , bio=jstring('bio')
) %>% 
enter_object('topics') %>% 
gather_array %>%
spread_values(urlkey=jstring('urlkey'))
```

This pipeline really shines if there are multiple such objects in the array.  Hope that is helpful, even if very long after the fact!

Comment: Great, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The object produced by `as.tbl_json` is a bit odd to my way of thinking, with a single item having the name, `document.id`, and a value of 1. Among its attributes is one called `JSON`:

```
json <- '
     [{"country":"us","city":"Portland","topics":[{"urlkey":"videogame","name":"Video Games","id":4471},{"urlkey":"board-games","name":"Board Games","id":19585},{"urlkey":"computer-programming","name":"Computer programming","id":48471},{"urlkey":"opensource","name":"Open Source","id":563}],"joined":1416349237000,"link":"http://www.meetup.com/members/156440062","bio":"Analytics engineer.  Primarily work in the Hadoop space.","lon":-122.65,"other_services":{},"name":"Aaron Wirick","visited":1443078098000,"self":{"common":{}},"id":156440062,"state":"OR","lat":45.56,"status":"active"}]
     '
    obj <-  json %>% as.tbl_json

> dput(obj)
structure(list(document.id = 1L), .Names = "document.id", row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_json", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), JSON = list(list(structure(list(country = "us", 
    city = "Portland", topics = list(structure(list(urlkey = "videogame", 
        name = "Video Games", id = 4471L), .Names = c("urlkey", 
    "name", "id")), structure(list(urlkey = "board-games", name = "Board Games", 
        id = 19585L), .Names = c("urlkey", "name", "id")), structure(list(
        urlkey = "computer-programming", name = "Computer programming", 
        id = 48471L), .Names = c("urlkey", "name", "id")), structure(list(
        urlkey = "opensource", name = "Open Source", id = 563L), .Names = c("urlkey", 
    "name", "id"))), joined = 1416349237000, link = "http://www.meetup.com/members/156440062", 
    bio = "Analytics engineer.  Primarily work in the Hadoop space.", 
    lon = -122.65, other_services = structure(list(), .Names = character(0)), 
    name = "Aaron Wirick", visited = 1443078098000, self = structure(list(
        common = structure(list(), .Names = character(0))), .Names = "common"), 
    id = 156440062L, state = "OR", lat = 45.56, status = "active"), .Names = c("country", 
"city", "topics", "joined", "link", "bio", "lon", "other_services", 
"name", "visited", "self", "id", "state", "lat", "status")))))
```

Looking at that you can see that in order to get at the names of the embedded list object that is the value of that attribute you need to do this:

```
 names( attr(obj, "JSON")[[1]][[1]] )
#------------
 [1] "country"        "city"           "topics"         "joined"         "link"          
 [6] "bio"            "lon"            "other_services" "name"           "visited"       
[11] "self"           "id"             "state"          "lat"            "status"
```

Wish I could be more help, but at least you understand where the error was coming from. (I also wish there were more example on the help pages of that package.)

Comment: Thanks!  That adds a trick to my diagnostic toolkit at lets me look under the hood although it doesn't solve my problem!

Comment: `dput` gives you more information than just using `str`.